Activar dos scroll al mismo tiempo: uno en body y otro en div
En mi proyecto tengo un sistema de navegación por pestañas (tab) que contiene extenso contenido cada uno.
Este dónde esté la etiqueta nav, al hacer click sobre un nombre, se muestra su contenido y se genera un scroll para que la etiqueta nav quede arriba y se vea en pantalla el contenido.
El problema es que el contenido pagina queda a mitad de camino. Por ejemplo si se vio hasta abajo de la pagina y al cambiar de pagina, éste sigue abajo y no se genera scroll hasta arriba.
Quisiera que, al igual que en el body se hace scroll (que funciona bien), también lo haga en el contenido pagina.
Al seleccionar uno, se abre la página y se hace el scroll hasta donde está su indicador id
Aquí el código comentado es lo que quiero lograr
pagina.forEach( ev => {
  if(este.dataset.pagina == ev.id) {
    ev.classList.add("activo");

    // Esto es lo que quiero lograr
    //ev.scroll({top: 0, behavior: "smooth"});

} else ev.classList.remove("activo");
});

Y el scroll en el body que funciona bien es así:
const scrolHacia = e.target.getAttribute("data-scroll");
const scrol = document.getElementById(`${scrolHacia}`);
scrol.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});

En síntesis, estando al pie de página y si se cambia de página (tab), el scroll no vuelve arriba.


const headland = document.getElementById("headland");
const header = document.querySelector("header");
const headerCaja = document.querySelector("header .caja");
const yoNavegacion = document.getElementById("yoNavegacion");
const yoNavegacionItem = document.querySelectorAll("#yoNavegacion li"); 
const yoNavegacionBarra = document.getElementById("yoNavegacion-barra");
const pagina = document.querySelectorAll(".pagina");

const observar = new IntersectionObserver( ([e]) => {
            if (e.intersectionRatio < 0.1) activar = true;
            else activar = false;
},{ threshold: 0.1 });

observar.observe(header);

let scrolInicial = 0;
let alturaHeadland = headland.getClientRects()[0].height;
let alturaHeader = header.getClientRects()[0].height;
let activar = false;

window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => { 
            
            headerCaja.style.opacity = 1 - + window.pageYOffset/alturaHeader + "";
            headerCaja.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrolInicial * 0.4 + 'px)';
            
            if(activar) {
                            if (scrolInicial > this.scrollY) {  
                                            headland.style.top = "0px";
                                            headland.classList.add("visible");
                                            yoNavegacion.style.top = `${alturaHeadland}px`;
                            } else {
                                            headland.style.top = `${-alturaHeadland}px`;
                                            yoNavegacion.style.top = "0px";
                            }
            } else {
                            headland.style.top = "0px";
                            headland.classList.remove("visible");
                            yoNavegacion.style.top = "0px";
            }
            
            scrolInicial = this.scrollY;
});

function paginacionPagina(e) { // Alternar (páginas) sección contenido 
            
            const este = e.target;
            yoNavegacionItem.forEach(ev => ev.classList.remove("activo"));
            este.classList.add("activo");
            
            pagina.forEach( ev => {
                            if(este.dataset.pagina == ev.id) {
                                ev.classList.add("activo");
                                //ev.scroll({top: 0, behavior: "smooth"});
                            }
                            else ev.classList.remove("activo");
            });
            
            yoNavegacionBarra.style.width = e.target.offsetWidth + "px";
            yoNavegacionBarra.style.left = e.target.offsetLeft + "px";

            scrolear(e);
};

function scrolear(e) { // Scrolear en la página
            
            const scrolHacia = e.target.getAttribute("data-scroll");
            const scrol = document.getElementById(`${scrolHacia}`);
            
            scrol.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
            //pagina.scroll({top: 0, behavior: "smooth"});
};

yoNavegacionItem.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", paginacionPagina));
:root {
    --alturaNormal: 75px;
    --transicionNormal: all 0.3s ease;
    --sobreImagen: rgba(251 251 254 / 0.5); 
    --enlaceClaroTransparente: rgba(135 206 235 / 0.5);
    @media(width < 576px) {
            --alturaNormal: 50px;
    }
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
}

.headland {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--alturaNormal);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    background-color: var(--sobreImagen);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    transition: var(--transicionNormal)
} .headland.visible {
    background-color: whitesmoke
} .menu {
    border-radius: .20rem;
    border: 0;
    padding: .20rem .30rem
} header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh
}

main {
    min-height: 100vh
}

.caja {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
} .caja img, .caja video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover
} .sobre {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    right: 1rem;
    width: 450px;
    height: 575px;
    border-radius: .30rem;
    background-color: var(--sobreImagen);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    @media(width < 576px) {
            right: unset;
            width: 275px;
            height: 350px
    }
} .absoluto-arriba, .sobre {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1
} .absoluto-arriba {
    top: 0;
    left: 0
} .logo {
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 1.50rem;
    transition: var(--transicionNormal);
    @media(width < 576px) {
            font-size: 1.25rem
    }
} .yoNavegacion {
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: var(--alturaNormal);
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    transition: var(--transicionNormal)
} .yoNavegacion ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: var(--alturaNormal)
} .yoNavegacion li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--alturaNormal);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    cursor: pointer
} .yoNavegacion li:first-child {
    width: 100px
} .yoNavegacion li.activo {
    font-weight: bold
} .yoNavegacion-barra {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 95px;
    height: var(--alturaNormal);
    background-color: var(--enlaceClaroTransparente);
    transition: var(--transicionNormal)
}

.pagina {
    display: none;
    height: 3000px; /* para la demostracion */
    scroll-margin-top: 250px 
} 

.pagina.activo {
    display: block
}
<headland class="headland" id="headland">
            
                    <button class="menu">Menú</button>
                    <h1 class="logo"> Nombre de Página</h1>
            
    </headland>
    
    <header>
            
    </header>
    
    <main>
            
            <nav class="yoNavegacion" id="yoNavegacion">
                    <ul>
                            <li class="activo" data-pagina="todos" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Todos</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="primero" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Primero</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="segundo" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Segundo</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="tercero" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Tercero</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="cuarto" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Cuarto</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="quinto" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Quinta parte</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="sexto" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Sexto</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="septimo" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Séptimo</li>
                            <li class="" data-pagina="ultimo" data-scroll="yoNavegacion">Último</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="yoNavegacion-barra" id="yoNavegacion-barra"></div>
            </nav>
            
            <section class="pagina activo" id="todos">
                    <h1>Todos</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="primero">
                    <h1>Primero</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="segundo">
                    <h1>Segundo</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="tercero">
                    <h1>Tercero</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="cuarto">
                    <h1>Cuarto</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="quinto">
                    <h1>Quinta parte</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="sexto">
                    <h1>Sexto</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="septimo">
                    <h1>Séptimo</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="pagina" id="ultimo">
                    <h1>Último</h1>
            </section>
            
    </main>
    
    <script>
    let datos = [{
    video: "BigBuckBunny.mp4",
    titulo: "BigBuck Bunny"
},{
    video: "ElephantsDream.mp4",
    titulo: "Elephants Dream"
},{
    video: "ForBiggerFun.mp4",
    titulo: "For Bigger Fun"
}];
    
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * datos.length);
    const aqui = document.querySelector("header");
    const crear = document.createElement("div");
    crear.classList.add("caja","absoluto-arriba");
    
    crear.innerHTML = `
    <div class="sobre">
                            <h1>${datos[i].titulo}</h1>
    </div>
    <video muted src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/${datos[i].video}">
    `;
    
    aqui.appendChild(crear);
    const video = crear.querySelector("video");
    video.load();
    video.play();
    </script>




no seria mas fasil agrupar estas pestañaas en submenus? es mas estetico,funcional y ordenado fuera de que se adapta mejor a mobile ...

Es que en estás secciones tengo todo el contenido que voy a mostrar. No es un menú horizontal. El menú principal ya tengo arriba a la izquierda. Y todo tengo responsivo. Solo que este está resumido solo para el ejemplo
